# Meaning of green up and red down arrows next to unit cover shield?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I've noticed some of my soldiers occasionally have a green ^ or a red ^ (upside down) next to their cover icon.

What is the meaning of this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

These indicate stat penalties and bonuses. For example, if a unit is suppressed, it gets a -30 aim penalty. This unit will then have a red downward arrow next to the shield to indicate it has a stat penalty.

Comment: I'm looking for a list of penalties and bonuses, but I'm at work at the moment, so I can't look too hard.

Comment: I assume if I examine the unit's info panel it will say what the active influences are, yes?

Comment: I believe it will, yes.